# Set ls color listings based on regex instead of globbing

Tags: shell, colors, ls

Is it possible to set regex patterns for color matching in the LS_COLORS variable? So instead of just

`*.jpg=38;5;220`

Can I do

`\.(jpg|gif)=38;5;220`

That's just an example, I'd like to get more complicated than that. Am I asking too much from this? Is there another way to do terminal color schemes that I can get fancier?

I'm using zsh btw, so if I can do it there but not bash, that's fine.

Answer (score 7):

That's a feature of the `ls` utility in [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). It doesn't depend on the shell. The syntax is not documented (you're supposed to use `dircolors` and figure it from there), but a quick look at the source shows that the only way to match files by name is to use `*` followed by a string which must be a suffix for a file name to match. The string is interpreted literally, except that `\` and `^` introduce escape sequences (e.g. `\n` = `^J` = newline).

So you can't match different extensions with the same pattern. But you can use shell programming constructs to build `LS_COLORS`:

```
for ext in jpg gif; do LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:*.$ext=38;5;220"; done
```